# Scraping product information from table using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

'''I'm unable to scrape ingredients from table with my code. Please help me with my code. I want only ingredients name as a output. I've also provided the image of ingredients table. Here, I only want the ingredients names marked with a red circle.[image: I've also provided the image of ingredients table. Here, I only want the ingredients names marked with a red circle]'''

```
url=https://mamaearth.in/product/mamaearth-me-deo-for-a-scent-that-s-unique-to-you-120-ml
table1 = soup.find('div', class_='CmsItemRevamp-sc-1moss4z-0 eQqUUy CMSContent').text.strip()
table1
mydata = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    row_data = j.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in row_data]
    length = len(mydata)
    mydata.loc[length] = row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is in the HTML, but it is rendered using Javascript. As such you need to extract it yourself from JSON contained inside a `<script>` section of the HTML.

This could be done as follows:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

url= "https://mamaearth.in/product/mamaearth-me-deo-for-a-scent-that-s-unique-to-you-120-ml"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
script_text = soup.find('script', id="__NEXT_DATA__").string
data = json.loads(script_text)
soup_product = BeautifulSoup(data['props']['initialProps']['pageProps']['cmsContent'][5]['content'], "html.parser")

for tr in soup_product.find_all('tr'):
    print(tr.td.get_text(strip=True))   # display just the first td element
```

I suggest you `print(data)` to see all the available information that is returned. The hardest part is finding the location inside the JSON structure for what you need.

This would give you the following output:

```
Ingredient
Ethyl Alcohol (95%)
Aqua (D.M.Water)
Propylene Glycol
Perfume
```

Note: Some of the JSON values contain HTML which is why a second call to BeautifulSoup is used to parse this embedded HTML.

An alternative approach would be to use something like selenium to control your browser. This would render the HTML as you see when using view source. The downside is it is MUCH slower and resource intensive.

To output the ingredients on one line:

```py
ingredients = [tr.td.get_text(strip=True) for tr in soup_product.find_all('tr')][1:]        # [1:] to skip header
print(','.join(ingredients))
```

Comment: @Martin_Evans Thanks for the code. Just tell me one thing, how do you get this (['props']['initialProps']['pageProps']['cmsContent'][5]['content'])... is there any way to search faster for the content in this manner rather then wasting time on reading whole JSON structure. I always gets confused in JSON structures like which is the key and which is the value.

Comment: The JSON is converted to nested Python structures. I printed the raw JSON and used an online formatter to make it easier to read. I then located the data you wanted and used a tool to tell me the path for that element in the JSON. This is much safer than trying to parse the text yourself.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the tool and online formatter which I can use  to read JSON data??

Comment: Just search "json online formatter". I happen to use a json plugin for VSCode that displays the JSON path when editing JSON files

Comment: Hey @Martin Evans ... Sorry for bothering you again, but can I get the above output on a single line separated by comma??

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how